# Queueing for the Rødby-Puttgarden ferry

Tags: germany, driving, ferries, denmark

Driving south again this summer from Sweden to Germany. We normally wing it when it comes to ferries and it normally is no problem. However one may expect that there could be quite some waiting time at Rødby (and Puttgarden when going home) a sunday in July. What is the worst waiting time to expect? And is it worthwhile to book in advance (and put restrictions on our freedom obviously)?

[image]

[Photo](https://www.flickr.com/photos/granding/7583873380) by grading

Answer (score 1):

It's very difficult to predict the waiting time.

As for pricing the differences are significant. Check out the pricing table here: [Danish](https://www.scandlines.dk/billetter/billettyper-og-priser/rodby-puttgarden.aspx), [English](http://www.scandlines.com/tickets-und-tarife/tickets-and-prices/puttgarden-rodby.aspx).

Comment: Why is it difficult to predict the waiting time? Are there any days which are busier than others? How about specific hours during the day? Add some details, be pedagogical, make this a great answer. :) Oh, and welcome to the site.